# Cordova Crosswalk Blurry Content

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I am using crosswalk webview for Cordova 7.0.1 (I have also tried latest cordova i.e. 8.0.0) to package my HTML5 canvas game.
The problem is that the content is very blurry.
[image]

Here is the config.xml configuration that I am using.

```
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="sensorLandscape" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="22+" />
<preference name="xwalkCommandLine" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect --force-device-scale-factor=1 --disable-touch-drag-drop --disable-pinch" />
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
```

I am also using viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check like this :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().width;
canvas.height = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `viewport` meta tag with this one that also ensures zoom, width and height are fixed at 100%.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```